# ¿Qué aplicación le puedo dar a un cliente ligero?

Tags: linux, windows

Necesito aprender mas sobre el tema para hacer un proyecto pero solo tengo la idea y no consigo cursos o libros al respecto

Comment: Bienvenido bro, no lo tomes a mal pero tu pregunta no cumple con los requisitos del sitio, por ende te invito a que te des un paseo por [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] y asi aprendes sobre como preguntar y de paso ganas tus primeras medallas... ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay un proyecto de la comunidad GNU/Linux que se llama LTSP (Linux Terminal Server Project). Puedes encontrar informacion del mismo es http://www.ltsp.org/

Los clientes ligeros es un modelo de computadora **cliente-servidor**. 
En el que los clientes son equipos de escasos recursos, es decir que puede que:
- No tengan disco duro
- Tienen muy poca memoría RAM
- Tienen poca capacidad de procesamiento
- Tienen poca memoria de tarjeta grafica.

Estos clientes ligeros entonces estan interconectados en red con un servidor, el cual es una PC de características superiores a los de los clientes.
Este servidor se encarga de recibir y contestar peticiones de los clientes.

El LTSP es maravilloso y es algo de las cosas que me atrajo de Linux.
Solo imagina este escenario:
Tienes 2 equipos en tu casa un Pentium II, 128 Mb de RAM y no tienen disco duro.
Pero tambien tienes contigo un Intel 3, con 4Gb de Ram y 500 GB de disco duro.
Tu podrías instalar en esa PC de buenas caracteristicas en caso de tener Linux el servicio de LTSP, implementarías una pequeña red en la que tus tres maquinas esten interconectadas, con la configuracion correcta.

Si tu tienes por ejemplo instalado Linux Mint, entonces tu servidor distribuiría por red su sistema operativo y esos dos clientes al arrancar, podrían ejecutar el Linux Mint y todo las aplicaciones que esten ejecutando ellas de este sistema operativo en realidad se estarían ejecutando del lado del servidor. Es decir que toda la carga cae en el servidor.
Es muy interesante yo te invito que te documentes acerca de este proyecto (LTSP), saludos.

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real; o que solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: oh gracias amigo